# Trying to compile Cyberduck and ant error

Tags: java, macos, ant

I am trying to compile Cyberduck from SVN on MacOSX, I have run make to get the xcode project and tried to run 'build and compile' from the GUI and everything seemed to went well until getting that error :

/Users/chmouel.boudjnah/tmp/cyberduck/build-mac.xml:187:0 /Users/chmouel.boudjnah/tmp/cyberduck/build-mac.xml:187: Problem: failed to create task or type scp

```
Cause: Could not load a dependent class com/jcraft/jsch/UserInfo
       It is not enough to have Ant's optional JARs
       you need the JAR files that the optional tasks depend upon
       Ant's optional task dependencies are listed in the manual.


Action: Determine what extra JAR files are needed, and place them in one of:
        -/usr/share/ant/lib
        -/Users/chmouel.boudjnah/.ant/lib
        -a directory added on the command line with the -lib argument


Do not panic, this is a common problem.
The commonest cause is a missing JAR.
This is not a bug; it is a configuration problem
Total time: 5 minutes 4 seconds
```

I have add this file ~/.ant/lib/ant-jsch.jar and still no luck. Do you know if I am missing some files or some environment variable ?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [jsch-0.1.42.jar](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/com/jcraft/jsch/0.1.42/jsch-0.1.42.jar) jar in your classpath

Comment: Probably best to go to a later version (0.1.44 is latest at the moment) unless Cyberduck enforces 0.1.42.  I'm working on getting jsch into maven central

Answer (score 0):

Copy the dependencies for Ant from */lib/ext to ~/.ant/lib/*.jar*. This is documented in the [Readme](http://svn.cyberduck.ch/trunk/README.txt).